# select value against minimum value in group by

Tags: sql

This is the data in my table

```
XDATE       AC      BN      XPASS           UCODE   LVL
31-AUG-13   C-3     301     25-SEP-13       5465189  4
31-AUG-13   C-3     304     25-SEP-13       5465189  4
31-AUG-13   C-1     104     27-SEP-13       1000020  3
31-AUG-13   C-1     104     27-SEP-13       6461005  4
```

This is the query that I am executing

```
select 
    AC,
    BN,
    (case when count(*)>1 then 'Forwarded' else 'Prepared' end) status,
    min(LVL) 
from adsalarypreparationdtl 
group by AC,BN
```

This gives me the following result:

```
AC       BN         STATUS         LVL
C-1      104        Forwarded       3
C-3      301        Prepared        4
C-3      304        Prepared        4
```

I found everything, but I also want UCODE according to minimum value of LVL

Like this for example:

```
AC       BN      STATUS     UCODE       LVL
C-1      104     Forwarded  1000020     3
C-3      301     Prepared   5465189     4
C-3      304     Prepared   5465189     4
```

Please help.

Comment: Which is your database? MS sql server, oracle, MySql etc.?

Comment: Please stop posting in all uppercase letters, because it's like shouting and is considered rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select q1.*,q2.ucode
from (YourQuery) q1
left join adsalarypreparationdtl q2
on q1.ac=q2.ac and q1.bn=q2.bn and q1.minlvl=q2.lvl
```

In your query you should alias the min(lvl) column as minlvl.

Probably it is not efficient but will work.

Edit: Do you need any special handling in case there are 2 or more rows with the same lvl?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select AC,
       BN,
       ucode, 
       lvl
from (
    select ac, 
           bn,
           ucode,
           lvl, 
           row_number() over (partition by AC,BN order by lvl) as rn
    from adsalarypreparationdtl 
) t 
where rn = 1;
```